# How to use Lat/Lon in machine learning prediction?

Tags: neural-network, predictive-modeling, machine-learning-model, feature-engineering, geospatial

I am research meteorologist working with hurricane model forecasts of track (millions of lat/lon pairs) and their verified lat/lon pairs (essentially where the hurricane *actually* went).

With the research I am conducting I'll be using several different machine learning techniques and IDEALLY i'd love train a machine learning model on a set of hurricane models (say 5 models) and their forecasted (The X's or X_train data) lat/lon pairs and the verified locations (Y's or Y_train) at lets say, 24 hours from the current time. Then use, say todays lat/lon pair forecasts from those 5 models of a hurricane in the Atlantic ocean in 24 hours to make an artificially intelligent forecast of the lat/lon pair.

I have looked into feature crossing from tensor flow but cant seem to figure out if this would do well with lat/lon data. Additionally I have  looked around for help with the possibility of representing the lat/lon pairs as single points but those efforts have been largely inconclusive. Outside of that, I am unaware of how to approach this problem.

It should also be mentioned this work will all be done in python.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!